# Retrieve html/aspx source code using telnet and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telnet, hta

I need to get the source of aspx page that is stored on my company's server, I don't have access to the server (***Or any server - so server language not considered***), I'm using HTA localy on my PC.

I wrote this code: (JavaScript)

```
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("telnet -fh:/telnetlog.txt xxx.xxx.xxx.com 80"); //The host address


setTimeout("WshShell.SendKeys('GET /subfolder/page.aspx HTTP/1.0~~')",1000);
```

It worked at home with many pages, but now I've got HTTP/1.1 401..

What can I do about it? I'm getting to this page from IE with no problems.
Any other ideas also be considered!

Thanks,
Rotem

Comment: I'm confused... assuming a properly configured server, telneting to port 80 of a web server and requesting a page (regardless of whether it's aspx or html) will return a HTML page, not aspx source code.  It'd be the same thing you get by viewing source in a browser.  How could it possibly get the aspx code before?

Comment: @Jeff: There are two ways.  The first involves a misconfigured server: one that doesn't have .net installed and therefore IIS just serves the contents of the .aspx page it finds as if it was a text file.  The second involves an unpatched server (probably using a padding oracle attack) which would force the server to give up it's contents.  Either way, you are right in that this should never work on a production system.

Answer (score 1):

401 means the server wants you to authenticate, probably with NTLM. I seriously doubt it's possible to implement NTLM using JScript and telnet.

HTA's run with lower security than regular web pages - as such, you might be able to get the page with a cross site XmlHttpRequest. That will go through IE's security layer, which should (?) provide the request with the NTLM credentials from your browser.

---

Using an XmlHttpRequest from an HTA is just like using one from a browser:

```
var url = "http://my-server/my-page.aspx";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        do_something(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.send();
```

The `responseText` parameter will contain the server's response (the HTML).

You should also be able to use a javascript library like jQuery instead of writing your own support code.

Comment: It isn't working, I get error in the line 'xhr.open("GET", url, true); ' Maybe because this isn't my server - again?

Answer (score 1):

Just so I understand: 
You want to download the aspx code for a web page on a server that you do not have access to?  Seriously?

Just call the network admin.  If you really work for that company AND are authorized to get this info then they can help you out.

If not then, I hope others on SO have better presence of mind than to try and hack a machine for you.

Comment: I'm working at this company as representive and not in a job related to the computers systems, I built this HTA the help us with several things, among those things there is an aspx page that has one query in it, I want to build a page in my HTA that sending a query in the same way, but takes the respond and finds inside it important stuff for me and highlight them.. Any thoughts?